# How to run .NET 4.5 apps on a machine

Tags: .net

I recently installed RC 12 of Visual Studio and have created an app using some of the new features in .NET 4.5.

This app runs fine under VS but when I run it from the command line I get the error to the effect that the assemblies were built with a runtime different than the currently loaded runtime.

Not quite sure how to get around this??

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This happen on the same machine where you have written yuor app?

Comment: What messages do you get with Code Analysis? Every time I change my apps from a VS version to another one, I need to perform an extensive CA check to be sure that everything must work as expected at least

Comment: Why RC when RTM is out? Posting the exact error message would be better for your question.